# C# generic T function where T is from a string

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I'm creating a synchronize function between a device and server for a large database. I have a lot of listing tables (the items in a dropdown/picker).
I don't want to write a lot of code and I'm looking for an elegant solution :)

On a device in SQLite I defined listing table like

```
    public class NameTable : IBusinessEntity {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

When I save in database a new record (item) I call this function

```
    public int SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : IBusinessEntity {
        lock (locker) {
            if (item.Id != 0) {
                database.Update(item);
                return item.Id;
            }
            else {
                return database.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when the device receives a new record from the server the structure is like

```
    public class SyncResult {
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public int ServerId { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I want to save (insert a new record if *DeviceId == 0* or update an existing item).

My question is: how can I call *SaveItem* where *T* is the *TableName* from *SyncResult*?

Thank you in advance for any help (I can offer a beer for that!)

---

`SaveItem` is a member of `MyDatabase` class. Basically my problem is how to pass to `SaveItem<T>` the T as string.

I don't know if I explained clearly my issue.

Comment: are you using Entity Framework ?

Comment: No in this case. It's SQLite in Xamarin Forms

Comment: You want T to be a string? Why not just use string then? It shouldn't be generic if you're limiting it down to one type.

Comment: You could try: MyClass item = new MyClass(); then item.GetType().Name Or create a `CustomAttribute` to specify a TableName for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map a `TableName` to a `Type` for example `Dictionary<string,Type>` Use the `Activator` class to construct the type. Use reflection to fill the data.

Comment: Thanks. When I invoke an `Activator`, can I receive something in return? For example to update a record I have to read the current record and the update it.

Comment: And I can select GetMethod or GetMethodRuntime or something else?

Comment: If you inherit all Types from `IBusinessEntity`. You can cast it to `IBusinessEntity`   for example: `IBusinessEntity myObj = (IBusinessEntity)Activator.Create(typeNameStr)`  You might move something like the `SaveItem` method to the Interface.